# Regex to remove quotes from img tag

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, image

I need to remove all quotes from an image tag found within lots of other text.  For example, I want to make

```
<img src="folder/image.gif" target="_blank" />
```

into

```
<img src=folder/image.gif target=_blank />
```

I'm using vb, and need to use a regEx specifically for the img tag and not use replace.  The img tag can be in a block of other text, so I need to use regEx to search for the `<img` and then within that until I meet a `/>` I need to remove all quotes.  Is that better?  Thanks so much for your patience - I had an emergency at work today.

Comment: You want to turn valid HTML into invalid HTML? (The `/` is not valid to include in an unquoted attribute and technically would mean the end of the tag in HTML4.) Well, I suppose regex hacking *is* the traditional way to generate hopelessly broken markup...

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is replace quotes, you don't even need a regex -- your language's string replacement function will suffice. In C#, this would be [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx):

```
string noQuotes = myString.Replace('\"', '');
```

What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
theUrl.Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using? You might be able to get away with a string replace function. PHP has a nice one `str_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read in the string in javascript, all you need to do is `str.replace("\"", "")`. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work if anyone else needs it:  (?i)(?<=]*)["]